# Index not picked up on nullable boolean column

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, timescaledb

I have 2 TimescaleDB Databases (PROD and DEV), both have a hypertable with the same schema and almost the same data (44M rows for the first one, 40M for the 2nd one).

I have to query some data on a boolean column

```
SELECT * FROM pumpcards
WHERE to_label = TRUE
ORDER BY starttime DESC;
```

Because I only have couple cards (1xxx) with a non-null value I created an index:

```
CREATE INDEX to_label_true ON pumpcards (to_label)
WHERE to_label IS NOT NULL;
```

Now my SELECT on the dev db takes 500ms
but on prod it takes 25+sec and CPU goes to 100%

In my `explain analyse` of the query on DEV I can see that the index is being picked up:

`Index Cond: (to_label = true)`

But PROD is not using the index and it is filtering on `to_label`:

`Filter: to_label Rows Removed by Filter: 2164238`

I deleted all the index, re-created them, I also ran `VACUUM ANALYZE pumpcards`. No luck.

My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.pumpcards (
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('pumpcards_id_seq'::regclass),
    wellid integer,
    starttime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    endtime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    physical_card boolean NOT NULL,
    nb_points integer NOT NULL,
    "position" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    load text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    pressure text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    opti_gf double precision,
    ml_gf double precision,
    error_score double precision,
    novelty_score double precision,
    labeled boolean NOT NULL,
    manual_gf double precision,
    to_label boolean,
    erroneous_card boolean,
    fluid_pound boolean,
    gas_interference boolean,
    pump_tagging boolean,
    worn_top_valve boolean,
    worn_bottom_valve boolean,
    stuck_top_valve boolean,
    stuck_bottom_valve boolean,
    worn_barrel boolean,
    unanchored_tubing boolean,
    stuck_pump boolean,
    parted_rod boolean,
    solid_friction_along_rod boolean,
    solid_friction_in_pump boolean,
    tubing_leak boolean,
    tight_stuffing_box boolean,
    flumping boolean,
    depth_of_issue double precision,
    to_investigate boolean,
    position_downhole text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    load_downhole text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    work double precision NOT NULL,
    work_downhole double precision,
    gas_lock boolean,
    amplitude_dwl real,
    amplitude_sfc real,
    max_position real,
    min_position real,
    max_load real,
    min_load real,
    CONSTRAINT pumpcards_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, starttime),
    CONSTRAINT pumpcards_wellid_starttime_key UNIQUE (wellid, starttime)
)

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS pumpcards_id_idx
    ON public.pumpcards USING btree
    (id DESC NULLS FIRST);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS pumpcards_labeled_erroneous_card_idx
    ON public.pumpcards USING btree
    (labeled DESC NULLS FIRST, erroneous_card ASC NULLS LAST)
    WHERE manual_gf IS NOT NULL;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS pumpcards_starttime_idx
    ON public.pumpcards USING btree
    (starttime DESC NULLS FIRST);

CREATE INDEX to_label_true ON pumpcards (to_label)
WHERE to_label IS NOT NULL;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS pumpcards_wellid_starttime_idx
    ON public.pumpcards USING btree
    (wellid ASC NULLS LAST, starttime DESC NULLS FIRST);


CREATE TRIGGER ts_insert_blocker
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON public.pumpcards
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION _timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker();
```

Example `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in PROD:

```
Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_53_2637_chunk  (cost=0.00..98436.09 rows=1 width=400) (actual time=10555.252..10555.253 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Filter: to_label
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2138437
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's a "hypertable" in a Postgres database? I see a plain table ... Why call the index `to_label_true` when the condition is `WHERE to_label IS NOT NULL`. Is `to_label = false` possible?

Comment: To rule out misunderstandings, please show the result for these two queries on PROD: `SELECT to_label, count(*), FROM public.pump_cards GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC;` And `SHOW search_path;`

Comment: Show the entire plans from both servers, not just one node.  If you have dozens of partitions, show at least a few of those nodes plus the rest of the plan levels, like the gathers and sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from what you report, the index *should* be used. There must be some kind of misunderstanding.

It's unclear which index we are talking about, exactly. You mention this one at the top:

```
CREATE INDEX to_label_true ON pumpcards (to_label)
WHERE to_label IS NOT NULL;
```

And show these two **different** indexes in the table description:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS pumpcards_to_label_starttime_idx
    ON public.pumpcards USING btree
    (to_label ASC NULLS LAST, starttime DESC NULLS FIRST)
    WHERE to_label IS NOT NULL;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS to_label_true
    ON public.pumpcards USING btree
    (to_label ASC NULLS LAST)
    WHERE to_label IS TRUE;
```

All distinct, and neither is optimal.
This would the perfect fit for your query:

```
CREATE INDEX to_label_true_starttime_desc ON public.pumpcards (starttime DESC)
WHERE to_label = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedbacks.
Sorry my question was not clear enough and my schema was not the latest version.

I ended up , finding the solution on TimescaleDB's Slack.

Apparently TimescaleDB version 2.5.1 had some problem with index.
Updating the version to 2.5.2 solved the problem and my query now execute in 200ms.

I then re-created the index and the execution time went down to 300ms.

Erwin your index is correct. Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Glad you managed to get the answer from the community Louis, thanks for sharing the underlying issue